# How to create a placeholder that starts from the top of the input box?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a message input box in a bootstrap form, however the box has to be of sufficient height so the user could read his message, the place holder of "message" would stay in the middle, also when I write the text it keeps going horizontally without considering margins, I am a newbie programmer so please don't be too harsh.

```css
.theform {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 5px solid;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.theform h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#formGroupExampleInput {
  height: 50px;
}

.form-control {
  font-size: 30px;
}

#messagebox {
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  line-height: 0px;
}

#message {
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  line-height: -20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="theform" id="link3">
  <h1 class="text-center">Contact</h1>
  <form>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Example label</label>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input" size="50">
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Another label</label>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input" size="50">
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Example label</label>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input" size="50">
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Example label</label>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="messagebox" placeholder="Message" size="50">
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your placeholder will only be visible on empty input fields, if you want it otherwise you will have to fake it with a label. If you want you text to not cut off on the right, then `input` is not the correct type of element, as input allows for a single line. Multiline can be accomplished using a `textarea`.

Comment: Do you want the placeholder to be centered vertically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a `textarea` instead of an `input`. If you want to center the placeholder vertically, you also have to use some JS, just to adjust the `textare`.

Just look into this codepen for an example implementation of a vertical centered `textarea`:
https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/gICqd

Comment: You don't need JS for this, there is the `placeholder` attribute. I think this answer was probably better off as a comment..

Comment: Mh. I just thought, he might want to center the placeholder vertically. If he does not want this, then you are right. So he can just replace the input with a textarea and use a placeholder.

Comment: Actually, his example shows the placeholder is already centered vertically, so I am assuming he wants it at the top. By default it is, so bootstrap must be adding something here...

Comment: Yeah, maybe you're right. Because of that, I've clearly focused my answer to the assumption of wanting the placeholder centered vertically.

Answer (score 0):

**NO JS REQUIRED**

you can fix this issue by puting the text area :

```
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

by default in text area the placeholder is sent to the top left.

Don't make the mistake of puting input instead because when you will give it a huge height the placeholder will be sent to the middle left !!!